# Entity Fluent API many-to-many table access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, fluent

When using many-to-many with fluent api, EF creates an extra couple-table for primary keys. This table is not in DBSet<>, so how do I access this table within my code? Should I add it to DbSet<>, or should I define this table and must not leave EF to create it?

Comment: Please post your entities so that we can help better

Comment: You only need to define the table if you are going to have non-key properties on it, otherwise just reference the collections on each side.

Comment: TableA and TableB has their PKs with many-to-many. After Update-Database, EF create TableATableB table containing reference to each tables FKs. How do I access TableA's > TableB details by id via TableATableB.

Answer (score 0):

If you let the model as is, not declaring any relation entity between A and B, then you can't access that table. But maybe you don't need it, because you can use navigation properties (collections) from A to B and B to A.

So if you need all B's associated with A, you will use a.Bs, and vice versa.

You can achieve any desired query result between A and B even if you don't access the relation table, and you would need to declare that table only if you need to add extra data to the relation.